# Show only countourplot lines inside regionplots, without displaying the regionplots [solved]

Tags: plotting, regions, intersection

I have a countorplot (Fun1) which important curves are those inside one of the two regionplots I'm working on (funA1 or funB2).
The minimal example of what I want to do is the following:

```
Fun1[a_, R_] := Sqrt[R] (-2 + Cot[1/4 Sqrt[3] a Sqrt[R]]^2) Tan[1/4 Sqrt[3] a Sqrt[R]]
funA1[a_, R_] := - Cos[1/4 Sqrt[3] a Sqrt[R]]^(1/3) Sin[1/4 Sqrt[3] a Sqrt[R]];
funB2[a_, R_] := -2 Sin[1/2 Sqrt[3] a Sqrt[R]] + 7 Sin[Sqrt[3] a Sqrt[R]];

(*scale in graphics*)
aminN001 = 0;      amaxN001 = 6;     RminN001 = 0;     RmaxN001 = 6;

(*Fun1[a_,R_] has to be cero, so I use ContourPlot*)
funCero = ContourPlot[Fun1[a, R] == 0, {R, RminN001, RmaxN001}, {a, aminN001, amaxN001}, ContourStyle -> {Black}, RotateLabel -> False, Frame -> True]
```

I obtain:

[image]

The two region I'm working on are defined as:

```
(*REGIONS*)

AreaA = RegionPlot[funA1[a, R] > 0, {R, RminN001, RmaxN001}, {a, aminN001, amaxN001}, 
   RotateLabel -> False, Frame -> True, BoundaryStyle -> {{Orange, Thin}}, PlotStyle -> {Transparent, Transparent}, Mesh -> 40, MeshStyle -> {Orange, Opacity[0.4]}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}];

AreaB = RegionPlot[funB2[a, R] > 0, {R, RminN001, RmaxN001}, {a, aminN001, amaxN001}, 
   Mesh -> 40, MeshFunctions -> {-#1 - #2 &}, MeshStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.4]}, RotateLabel -> False, Frame -> True, BoundaryStyle -> {{Blue, Thin}}, PlotStyle -> {Transparent, Transparent}];

Show[AreaA, AreaB, funCero]
```

If I display these two regions [in blue and orange] on the first graphic I obtain:

[image]

I would like to have a graphic that only shows the lines that are inside any of both regions, something like this
[the red arrow shows the curve that was inside the orange region, while the blue ones show the ones that were in the blue region]:
[image]

I know I can pick manually the values of the range in which I can draw the countourplot, but that doesn't automatise the procedure as I would like to do. In the original problem, I have regionplots with more complicated shapes for doing it manually.

I've tried to plot using ImplicitRegion, but it doesn't work

```
A = ImplicitRegion[{{funA1[a, R] > 0, funB2[a, R] > 0 } && Fun1[a, R] == 0}, {R, a}]
RegionPlot[A, PlotRange -> {{RminN001, RmaxN001}, {aminN001, amaxN001}}]
```

Edit: I finally managed to work around this. The key was "RegionFunction" in the ContourPlot like this:

```
ContourPlot[Fun1[a, R] == 0, {R, 0.001, 6}, {r, 0.001, 6}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{R, r}, FunA1[r, R] > 0 && FunA2[r, R] > 0 // Evaluate]]
```

Now I have problems with an error that happens only for certain values claiming Boolean function, though.

Comment: `RegionPlot[{funA1[a, R] >= 0, funB2[a, R] >= 0}, {R, RminN001, 
  RmaxN001}, {a, aminN001, amaxN001}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{R, a}, Fun1[a, R]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightOrange, HatchFilling[]], 
   Directive[LightBlue, HatchFilling[-30 Degree]]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]`

Comment: @cvgmt, thank you for the answer! although your answer produces dotted lines around the zones where the FunA1 and FunA2 are = 0. Could be possible to show only the MeshFunction related to Fun1 without the coloured zones and their borders?